# Macbook Pro, two external monitors, clamshell mode and heat

Tags: macbook-pro, display, closed-clamshell

I use my Macbook Pro 15 (mid 2015) with two Asus PA248Q monitors. It has Intel Pro gpu.

I was just wondering that does it matter heat wise if I keep the lid down?

The hinge seems to have some kid of deflector for the fan so it should push the hot air out.

I was just wondering that can I even stress the Macbook Pro 15 so much that it would cut off and shutdown at emergency heat limit?

Comment: FWIW I've been running my MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2013) in [closed-display mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201834) from a [BookArc](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/HJB32ZM/A/twelve-south-bookarc-stand-for-macbook) connected to a Thunderbolt Display while doing audio/video recoding and multi-tasking between numerous apps including running one or more virtual machines all simultaneously and have never had the system shutdown or any unwanted anomaly from overheating. In other words while it at times runs hot and the fans run high it has functioned as I expect the product to.

Comment: Glad to hear that. I am running Mathematica 10 and soon Matlab. Also bit of Debian 8 in virtual machine for Maxima and GAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) - Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP719):

> Operating temperature for the Macbook Pro Mid 2015: 50° to 95° F (10° to 35° C).

You should be able to use it in [closed-display mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201834) (a.k.a. closed-clamshell mode) just fine providing the back hinge has a way to dissipate heat appropriately. If it gets too hot, it will auto shut down after the max temperature is reached.